# Implement spring security SSO without redirect to auth server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have SSO configured with a **auth server** which hosts login page and sso functionality using OAuth2. I have several clients which redirect to this auth server login page whenever authentication is required.

What I am trying to achieve is to not redirect to this auth server login page, instead somehow if a client wants to have its own custom login page then user fills in username password there and internally client connects to auth server for authentication. Hence, a user never leaves the client website.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: you can use direct grant authentication flow, which generates token by using username and password with grant_type=password

Comment: @crack_iT Could you please elaborate it bit more or provide any link to some documentation. I tried to search for it, but not sure have found right thing or not

Comment: this can help https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant

Comment: also Resource owner credentials grant 

 in https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/